# Why aren't my edits being accepted?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I've tried to submit edits to answers for questions that I have asked but I never seem to get my edits accepted. Is that because the person that gave the answer won't accept the edit or are moderators preventing it?

I realize that it goes through review but in both instances my edit provides significant value to the original answer. Perhaps you need a certain number of reputation points?

Comment: You can see the responses to your edits here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/901376/occasl?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Ok, thanks for that but even after reading that, I don't understand why some of edits are not accepted when clearly they're beneficial. Take for instance my second edit. It's just plain wrong in the original answer. The subjective nature of the edit process makes it seem like a waste of time and so it seems just better to put another answer that expounds on the first answer, which to my mind is not correct because you're hijacking the original answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite frankly, these aren't edits.  You're attempting to modify an existing implementation provided by someone else into another answer.

This is the specific reject reason:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

You're modifying the contents of another post to be "more correct", when you should really comment on that instead, or make your own answer to be more correct.  In general, avoid edits that **modify context** or **alter answers**.

If you were to answer the question with your code, also explaining why you felt it were better than the other existing answers, that would fare *much* better.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood what an edit is for. I thought it was to improve an answer or as you put make it "more correct". That said, what is edit for? Spelling, grammar, things like that?

Comment: @occasl Yes. Spelling, grammar, formatting are more appropriate uses of edits. Sometimes small code edits are fine if you reference a comment discussion on the answer, but getting those accepted depends on the reviewers that see your edit.